# In The Meantime

Tags: phrase-meaning, ellipsis

A Google cache can show a web page as it appeared at a point in time in the past:

On a particular google cache page, this caption was found:

> [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2OhNCddwzcEJ:www.thestandard.com.hk/news_detail.asp%3Fpp_cat%3D11%26art_id%3D144348%26sid%3D42008076%26con_type%3D1+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)
>   It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on Jul 25, 2014 17:36:27 GMT. The current page could have changed ***in the meantime***.

what does "*in the meantime*" mean in this context.  According to dictionaries, "*meantime*" requires two referent points in time.  While July 25, 2014 is one, it is not clear what other reference point in time is.  Dictionaries seem to suggest that the second reference point could be a point in time in the past or future.

Comment: It can't be a future point in time—the sentence has *could have*, locating the change sometime before now.

Comment: @snailplane Would "The current page could have changed ***since***" be better?

Comment: No, it's better the way it is.

Comment: @snailplane  But, "*since*" also includes the period of time up to the present

Comment: @snailplane  The more I reread the original sentence and dictionaries, the more I think the original sentence is poorly written, because the second reference point in time is never indisputably indicated.

Comment: No, it's fine the way it is.

Comment: @snailplane But the second reference point in time could be in the past or present or future.  So, it is ambiguous.

Comment: No, it's not.  The second point in time is unambiguously the present.

Comment: @snailplane How do you figure out what the second point in time is?

Comment: You don't, explicitly, but "in the meantime" means "in the intervening span of time since".  Because we only referred to one point in time (the past, when the page was indexed), the only thing that makes sense is "between then and now".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase *in the meantime* is an adverbial phrase and it simply means during a particular time. Obviously, when it's *during* some time, it will have two points of time.

> [in the meantime](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/INTHEMEANTIME) - *During the intervening time*

If you see, it reads *the current page* which means the page that you are seeing ***now***. In the meantime is from the date specified (July 25, 2014) till the time you are seeing that page.

[Google cache](http://www.googleguide.com/cached_pages.html) takes a snapshot of almost all websites periodically. It simply means that the page is cached by Google. You can perform that action using [cache: URL] in Chrome. As I'm an SEO content writer, I can say that Google cache is very important to us. If the page is very new, it'll not display anything unless it's been cached by the bot.

Answer (score 7):

It does have two reference points, but the second one is less obvious.
The time period is July 25, 2014 17:36:27 GMT - current time.